# Unix shell script to search for error codes in thousand files then print the count in text file

Tags: linux, shell, loops, unix

I need to find both 150+ eventType and errorCodes in 1700 files each day.  That means i have to loop over 1700 files to find the occurrence count of 150+ eventType/errorCode and put those counts in a text file as a daily report.

I have placed those eventType/errorCode values in a text file separated by commas:

```
10008,4569
10008,4568
10003,1200
40000,4006
```

My initial code:

```
#!/bin/bash
DT=`date +%Y%m%d%H` //Today's date  
fileName=$(date --date="-1 day" +"%Y%m%d") //file name associated with yesterday's date
Yesterday=$(date --date="-1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d") //Yesterday's date
cd /advdata/datashareB/FFFF/continuousDownstream/` echo $Yesterday`

### Here I want to loop through text file that contains both errorCodes/eventsType and search them in 1700 files. in the loop i have to execute the following command:
###    eventExport -printEvents -file Run_`echo $fileName`*_*.tar -filter "ErrorCode=4569;EventType=10008"  -names -silent | wc -l
```

The output should be written to a text file in the following format:

```
Date            10008/4569  10008/4568   10003,1200  ...  ...
20160621         100            12800      58
........          ....          .....      ...  ....  ... ...
```

where the first row is the header and the second row is the total count of errorCodes/eventsType.

Every day the script should insert the values in the new line in the output file (text file).

How can I write this loop?

**EDIT:**
The file format is tar file like `Run_20160622_105700_02of04.tar`
. eventExport reads those tar files and extract error codes & eventTypes as given in the eventExport argument. the command is like:

```
eventExport -printEvents -file Run_20160526_09*_*.tar -filter "**ErrorCode=4569;EventType=10008**"  -names -silent | head | awk -F, '{OFS =","; print $3, $8,$9, $14}'
```

The output of is:

```
AccessKey="706385970",EventType=10008,OrigEventTime=2016-06-21 23:29:42.000,ErrorCode=4569
```

Here, eventsType is associated with errorCode. I have more than 150 eventTypes which i want to find them and get their counts in the tar files. tar files are more than 1700 file generated per day.

Comment: What is the input file format? I'd probably do it in awk, assuming text input. Or are you trying to parse the tar file directly?

Comment: i am trying to parse the tar file directly by using the following command:  ``eventExport -printEvents -file Run_`echo $fileName`*_*.tar -filter "ErrorCode=4569;EventType=10008"  -names -silent | wc`` -lit gives me the desired output. i.e. the count for ErrorCode=4569;EventType=10008" . but still i need to search for 150 ErrorCode and its EventType and get the output in a report format with heading as described in my question. for that i guess i have to use for loop.

Comment: Where does your "eventExport" command come from?

Comment: eventExport is a script provided by vendor. i want to put it inside a loop to get the count of all eventTypes along with errorCode.

Comment: Nobody here knows the vendor or the "eventExport" script. If you want help, you'll need to show us the file format and what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have updated my question .. plz have a look

Comment: It looks like `eventExport` is parsing, not generating, the tar files and extracting the lines for you. If `eventExport` can take more than one -filter arg, you can scan in only a few passes. Else, one pass per errorCode. Use `awk`, without the `head`, to keep totals as well and write them at the END. Seriously, you're 90% of the way there.

Comment: can you please give me code example? appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a GNU `awk` script (as its own script file, for reusability) that parses the event types and error codes the log file and reports the counts of matching event types and error codes for each date.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/ {
    # this line contains event type and error code

    split($0, data, ",");
    keys[data[1]][data[2]] = 0;
}

match($0, "EventType=([0-9]+).*ErrorCode=([0-9]+)", key) {
    # this line is from the log file

    if (key[1] in keys && key[2] in keys[key[1]]) {
        match($0, "OrigEventTime=([0-9-]+)", date);
        datecount[date[1]][key[1]][key[2]]++;
    }
}

END {
    for (d in datecount) {
        for (k1 in datecount[d]) {
            for (k2 in datecount[d][k1]) {
                printf("%s\t%s/%s\t%d\n",
                        d, k1, k2, datecount[d][k1][k2]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running it (note thot this *requires GNU `awk`*):

```
$ awk -f script.awk codes.txt run.log
```

The output is *not quite* in the format that you wanted, but I'm hoping it's close enough:

```
2016-06-11  10008/4569  1
2016-06-21  10008/4569  4
2016-06-21  40000/4006  1
```

(I duplicated the data that you gave us a few times and change a date and one of the event types and error codes).

**UPDATE**: I reworked the script for GNU `awk` versions older than 4.0 (that do not understand arrays of arrays):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/ {
    # this line contains event type and error code

    split($0, data, ",");
    keys[data[1],data[2]] = 1;
}

match($0, "EventType=([0-9]+).*ErrorCode=([0-9]+)", key) {
    # this line is from the log file

    if (keys[key[1],key[2]] == 1) {
        match($0, "OrigEventTime=([0-9-]+)", date);
        count[date[1],key[1],key[2]]++;
    }
}

END {
    for (comb in count) {
        split(comb, field, SUBSEP);
        printf("%s\t%s/%s\t%s\n", field[1], field[2], field[3], count[comb]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. i got the following error: ```awk: script.awk:7:     keys[data[1]][data[2]] = 0;
awk: script.awk:7:                  ^ syntax error
awk: script.awk:7:     keys[data[1]][data[2]] = 0;
awk: script.awk:7:                          ^ syntax error```

Comment: @Fshamri That is without doubt because your `awk` is not GNU `awk` and therefore does not understand the multidimensional arrays I've used. What Unix are you on? Is there a `gawk` command?

Comment: ```# type awk
awk is hashed (/usr/bin/awk``` ```# type gawk
gawk is hashed (/usr/bin/gawk)``` i use linux ```Linux kbl1infn1 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 6 18:30:54 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux```

Comment: @Fshamri In that case, try with `gawk` instead of `awk`... If that doesn't work let me know what `gawk --version` prints (version only). I'm using "GNU Awk 4.1.3". You would need version 4 or better.

Comment: thanks for trying to help. gawk also does't work  the awk version is ```GNU Awk 3.1.7```

Comment: @Fshamri Aw, shucks! Give me half an hour and I'll update the answer. Sorry!

Comment: script runs without errors. but i got no output because my source is not ```.log``` rather its ```.tar``` that is why  i have to use ```eventExport -printEvents -file Run_`echo $fileName`*_*.tar -filter "ErrorCode=4569;EventType=10008" -names -silent``` this commands parse the .tar files and extract the data. i guess we need to embed that command in our script.

Comment: @Fshamri Yes. You would need to extract the `tar` archive first. It's not easy parsing binary data, and I don't know the archive format for `tar` well enough to attempt it.

Comment: I will try. appreciate your support