# Search a word and count its occurrence in a file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to search for 3 words and count their occurrences in tens of files. those files names contains prefix + time stamp like  `FTM.FC102.20160623183001.20160623184500`
i want to search on them the following words: `Date` `OK` `RETRY` `DROP` then get their counts into new file. the desired output should be like:

```
    filename      OK    RETRY   DROP
    =================================
    XXX20160622XXX  221    305      400 //those values are the count of words
    .......   ... ...         ...
```

I have tries the following:

```
fileName=$(date --date="-1 day" +"%Y%m%d")
cd /advdata/ticketdatashareA/FTM_Sms/
format=*`echo $fileName`*
for i in $format;
do
 if [[ "$i" == "$format" ]]
 then
    echo "No Files"
 else
    echo -n "file name $i :" | cut -c21-49 ; echo  '\t' `grep OK $i | wc -l`; echo  '\t' `grep "RETRY" $i | wc -l`; echo  '\t' `grep "DROP" $i | wc -l`;
 fi
done
```

what i got is:

```
20160623134501.20160623140000
\t 107
\t 0
\t 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution for Bash:

```
declare -a words=( OK RETRY DROP )

echo "filename" "${words[@]}" | tr ' ' '\t'   # added in late edit

for file in FTM.FC102.*; do
    printf "$file "
    for word in "${words[@]}"; do
        grep -o "$word" "$file" | wc -l | tr '\n' ' '
    done
    echo
done | rs 0 $(( ${#words[@]} + 1 )) # alternatively:  | tr -s ' ' '\t'
```

Explanation:

- We store the words that we'll look for in the array `words`.
- Loop through the files (change the pattern to match your needs).
- For each file, we construct a line starting with the filename, then...
- For each word, `grep -o` on the file to get all matches for it.
- Count the number of matches (removing newlines from the end of the output of `wc` with `tr`).
- At the end of the line, emit a newline with a bare `echo` to end the line of output for this file.
- Pipe everything to `rs` to format the columns nicely. This utility is available on at least BSD system... If you don't have it, just remove the pipe and live with wonky columns, or use `| tr -s ' ' '\t'` instead, which does a half-decent job.

Does not print the header though.

With two files with the following contents:

```
$ cat text1
Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,
consectetur, adipisci velit...

$ cat text2
There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to
have it, simply because it is pain...
```

... and with the "words" `a`, `b` and `c`, the script does this:

```
$ bash script.sh
text1  4      0      3
text2  7      1      1
```

Comment: seems great. I have used ```done | tr -s 0' ' '\t'  $(( ${#words[@]} + 1 ))``` but got ```tr: extra operand `4'
Try `tr --help' for more information``` I am using redhat linux

Comment: for header, i will check if the output file is already exist do nothing else create new file and print the header. right?

Comment: @Fshamri Done. The headers might not be correctly aligned with the columns though, depending on the lengths of the filenames and the words...  Now I need to sleep!

Comment: it works as expected.. still i need to get the output into text file. can you help please?

Comment: @Fshamri Just redirect the output to a file: `bash script.sh >outfile`

Comment: thanks a lot. can you please look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949685/unix-shell-script-to-search-for-error-codes-in-thousand-files-then-print-the-cou?noredirect=1#comment63443092_37949685

Comment: @ Fshamri will do, but it's getting late here... :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

So, in general, say you have two files, a.txt and b.txt as follows..

*a.txt:*

```
cat dog cat
```

*b.txt*

```
dog cat dog
```

You want to count each occurrence of "cat" and "dog". This script works well for me, maybe it will help get you where you need to be:

*countem.bsh*

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.txt; do
  echo "$f,`grep -o cat $f | wc -l`,`grep -o dog $f | wc -l`" 
done
```

Output looks like:

```
a.txt,2,1
b.txt,1,2
```